# How to automate selecting options when Right click on Chrome using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The scenario is like this, When we open the chrome freshly and right click on the chrome page, you can see the options like Back, Forward, Reload, inspect etc. I want to automate the selection of these option in chrome using Selenium Python. How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to execute this through context menu or executing same actions via hotkeys is ok for you?

Comment: I am trying with the context menu. I need to use this only.